# SQL SERVER 2008 Dynamic query problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dynamic query which reads like this

```
Alter PROCEDURE dbo.mySP 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (
        @DBName varchar(50),
        @tblName varchar(50)

    )

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
declare @string as varchar(50)
declare @string1 as varchar(50)

set @string1  = '[' + @DBName + ']' + '.[dbo].' + '[' + @tblName + ']'

set @string = 'select * from ' + @string1   

exec @string
```

END

I am calling like this

```
dbo.mySP 'dbtest1','tblTest'
```

And I am experiencing an error

```
"Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure mySP, Line 27
The name 'select * from [dbtest1].[dbo].[tblTest]' is not a valid identifier."
```

What is wrong? and How to overcome?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do hope you're checking for SQL Injection somewhere...

Comment: I shuddder to think anyone would even consider writing an sp like this.  Please read:
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It thinks that the contents of `@string` refer to a stored procedure name. You need to put

```
EXEC (@string)
```

or better use the stored procedure `sp_executesql`

You should also set up some guard code to check that the values you are passing in are the names of real tables and databases. You can query the views in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to validate the input.

You can read more on [safer dynamic SQL](http://colinmackay.co.uk/blog/2009/09/21/if-you-really-must-do-dynamic-sql/) on my blog.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
exec @string
```

To

```
exec(@string)
```

Here's a working SP I just tested:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test] 
    @DBName varchar(50),
    @tblName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @string AS VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @string1 AS VARCHAR(50)

    SET @string1 = '[' + @DBName + '].[dbo].[' + @tblName + ']'
    SET @string = 'select * from ' + @string1

    EXEC(@string)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use EXEC as:

```
EXEC @String
```

it is trying to run a procedure with the name contained within the @String variable.  try it out:

```
create procedure TestProc
as
print 'you called TestProc!'
go

declare @string varchar(20)
set @string='TestProc'

exec @string
```

if you use EXEC as:

```
EXEC (@Query)
```

you run the sql within the @Query variable, try it out:

```
DECLARE @Query  varchar(50)
set @Query='Print ''just ran it!'''

EXEC (@Query)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE test_sp
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (
        @DBName varchar(50),
        @tblName varchar(50)

    )

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Insert statements for procedure here
declare @string as varchar(100)
declare @string1 as varchar(50)

set @string1  = '[' + @DBName + ']' + '.[dbo].' + '[' + @tblName + ']'
Print @string1
set @string = 'select * from'  + @string1       
Print @string
exec (@string)
SET NOCOUNT OFF  
END
```

Comment: What did you change? And why does this answer the question?